# Make a Default DIV (JS code)

Tags: javascript, css

this is a small question.

http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/TpF24/
in this example, i need that < div>Bar 1< /div> is open by default...

How can i do that?

That is all, Thank you very much!  :D

The JS code:

```
var current = null;

function showresponddiv(messagedivid){
    var id = messagedivid.replace("message-", "respond-"),
        div = document.getElementById(id);

    // hide previous one
    if(current && current != div) {
        current.style.display =  'none';
    }   

    if (div.style.display=="none"){
        div.style.display="inline";
        current = div;
    }
    else {
        div.style.display="none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Java `!=` Javascript, and CSS alone could fix that (for instance, a class or `style="display: block"` or whatnot).

Comment: Java is to JavaScript as Car is to Carpet

Comment: Well, how about just invoking `showresponddiv('message-1');` on `DOMReady` event?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `display: none` by default inside the HTML. Demo: [jslint](http://jsfiddle.net/TpF24/76/). 
Or as Gaby has suggested hide the div with javascript by invoking `showresponddiv('message-1')` on `windiw.load`.

Comment: This one?        current.style.display =  'none';

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
window.onload = function(){
    showresponddiv('message-1'); 
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/TpF24/79/